# How to write the query using linq?

Tags: linq, select

How to write the query using linq?

```
SELECT
    (SELECT SUM([quantity] * [price_usd])
        FROM [vi].[dbo].[SALES] 
        WHERE [type_id] =1 and [date_id] in(200701,200702,200703,200704,200705,200706,200707,200708,200709,200710,200711,200712)) as y2007,
    (SELECT SUM([quantity] * [price_usd])
        FROM [vi].[dbo].[SALES] 
        WHERE [type_id] =1 and [date_id] in(200801,200802,200803,200804,200805,200806,200807,200808,200809,200810,200811,200812)) as y2008,
        (SELECT SUM([quantity] * [price_usd])
        FROM [vi].[dbo].[SALES] 
        WHERE [type_id] =1 and [date_id] in(200901,200902,200903,200904,200905,200906,200907,200908,200909,200910,200911,200912)) as y2009
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about that kind of query:

```
From s in Sales
where s.type_id == 1
group s by s.date_id.ToString().Substring(0,4) into g
select New { Year = g.Key, Sum = g.Sum(i => i.quantity * i.price_usd) }
```

I have no opportunity to try it on iPad, but the idea is clear and it should work.

Comment: A very big thank you.   [0] { Year = "2011", Sum = 1192767121.5 } 
[1] { Year = "2009", Sum = 876670834.1617 }
[2] { Year = "2007", Sum = 620079972.1093 }
[3] { Year = "2012", Sum = 10859440.52 }
[4] { Year = "2008", Sum = 970709774.8901 }
[5] { Year = "2010", Sum = 1143741135.55 }

Comment: You should accept the answer if it helped you solve your problem. That's how SO works and how you can really thank other users for their answers.

Comment: group s by s.date_id.ToString().Substring(0, 4) - perhaps it will be a long time

Comment: If date_id is an integer, then it would be more efficient to do 'group s by s.date_id/10'

Comment: RESULT: var yearSum = from s in _db.SALEs
                          where s.type_id == 1 && s.date_id < 999999
                      group s by s.date_id / 100
                      into g
                      select new {Year = g.Key, Sum = g.Sum(i => i.quantity*i.price_usd)};